# How to explore functions in a go package

Tags: go

I am learning golang. I am looking for a handy way to explore the functions in a particular go package. For example, the commonly used strings package.

Comment: For the standard library, use [golang.org/pkg/](https://golang.org/pkg/). For other packages, try [pkg.go.dev/](https://pkg.go.dev/) and search for the package name. Running `go doc` yourself should only be if you have a much much older version or a private package.

Comment: any recommendation to explore custom packages from cmdline?

Comment: @Py_minion use the `go doc` command to explore custom packages from the command line.

Comment: @MuffinTop thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/fatih/vim-go.

It has linting feature for packages. Check the documentation https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that is helping in my learning of go is `go doc <pkg>`

```
 go doc strings
package strings // import "strings"

Package strings implements simple functions to manipulate UTF-8 encoded
strings.

For information about UTF-8 strings in Go, see
https://blog.golang.org/strings.

func Compare(a, b string) int
func Contains(s, substr string) bool
func ContainsAny(s, chars string) bool

.
.
.
.
```

Again, I am new to go programming language. I was looking for something similar to dir() in python. Please refer the help in go (go --help), so far it's quite helpful.

If anyone have any recommendation or can point me to a better approach, please let me knonw.

Comment: The online documentation? https://golang.org/pkg/strings/

Comment: something handy from terminal?

Comment: `go doc` is fine for terminal – online docs have the advantage of links to other places in the documentation and straight to the source code as well.